# How can I edit a script that calls find to search from a location passed as an argument?

Tags: bash

I have a homework that wants me to do this:

Write a script that, with the help of awk, scans all files that are changed today and has a size <= 1Mbyte (less or equal). The script should search all files recursively from the location you specify (arguments to the script) and list them to stdout (terminal).

I've done this so far:

```
find . -type f -size +1M -exec stat -c '%X %n' {} \; \
  | sort -nr \
  | awk 'NR==1,NR==3 {print $2}'
```

How do i manage to take paths as argument for the script and stdout all the results in the terminal? I may have done the find line incorrect aswell?

Comment: It's a very silly assignment to ask you to use awk for something `find` itself can do with only built-in functionality.

Comment: Anyhow, you've shown the *assignment*, and your attempt at it, but you haven't asked a question about the specific problem with *your code* which you encountered while doing it. It's not what you mean by "take the paths as an argument" -- what part of the assignment tells you to do that? And `print` in awk already *does* write to the terminal, though it's unclear why testing `NR` would be an appropriate way to decide which lines to print the second field from.

Comment: My problem is how do add argument functionality, lets the user write a path to folder to execute this functionality, and is my "find" correctly written based on the assignment?

Comment: If you want to let the user pass the location at which to start, change `find .` to `find "$@"`, or if you mean to accept only one argument (and want to default to `.`), maybe `find "${1:-.}"`. And edit the question to *ask* that thing explicitly.

Comment: BTW, your code would be faster to execute if you changed from `-exec stat ... {} \;` to `-exec stat ... {} +` -- that way `find` will pass multiple filenames to each `stat` call, rather than starting a whole new copy of `stat` for each file. But even better than that (so long as you're only targeting platforms with GNU find) would be to use `find -printf` and not need `stat` at all.

Comment: Keep saying this: sudo ./lastmodified.sh /Home/Desktop
find: ‘/Home/Desktop/’: No such file or directory

Comment: Why would you use `sudo` to access your own desktop? Anyhow, the most obvious explanation is that the error message is right and `/Home/Desktop` *doesn't* exist: `/Home` isn't a usual path, not present on either conventional UNIX or on MacOS; `"$HOME/Desktop"` is much more typical.

Comment: I think that you are missing the assignment's intent.  If you want to find all files recursively that meet some criteria, you can simply use find ( awk is superfluous ).  Given that, I would assume that the instructor wants you to write the entire function in awk.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing in `find` (the default on Linux). Just use the arguments of the script as the target directories:

```
#!/bin/sh
find "$@" -type f -size -2M -mtime -1
```

The `$@` expands to the list of arguments. The `-size -2M` means "smaller than 2M", but note that `find` will round up to the next unit. So a file that is 1.1M is considered 2M, which is why you want `-2M` and not `-1`. Finally, the `-mtime -1` finds only files modified within the past 24 hours.

Now, if your teacher wants you to somehow shoehorn `awk` into this, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

find "$@" -type f -mmin -1440 -exec stat -c '%s %n' {} + |
  awk '$1<=1048576'
```

Then, you run your script with the target directories as arguments:

```
foo.sh /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2 ... /path/to/dirN
```

If your teacher insists on doing the entire thing in `awk`, you could do:

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date +%s)
aDayAgo=$((now - 86400))
find "$@" -type f -mmin -1440 -exec stat -c '%s %X %n' {} + |
  awk -vaDayAgo="$aDayAgo" '$1<=1048576 && $2>=aDayAgo'
```

Of course, that means that your script will be off by as many seconds as it takes to run it since time will not stop while you're running it. But that's unlikely to be a serious issue.

Comment: One caveat: this puts the burden on the caller to ensure that a directory named (e.g.) `-foo` is passed as `./-foo` so that `find` doesn't mistake it for a primary.